# How to wake up threads of different instances?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I have many instances of the same object, and i would like to start a thread for each instance.
My threads should be synchronized, so each thread share a common object that I lock every time, as you can see in my code:

```
public Person(String name, Object1 o){
    this.name = name;
    this.obj1 = o;
}

public boolean addToList(){
    boolean locked;
    locked = obj1.getLock().tryLock();
    System.out.println(this.name+" try to lock");
    while (!locked){
        try{
            obj1.wait();
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
        locked = obj1.getLock().tryLock();
    }

    System.out.println(this.name+" lock ok");
    if(obj1.getPerson().size()<obj1.getNum()){
        System.out.println("0 "+name+" list size: "+obj1.getPerson().size());
        obj1.getPerson().add(this);
        System.out.println("1 "+name+" list size: "+obj1.getPerson().size());
        obj1.getLock().unlock();
        System.out.println("Unlock ok");
        obj1.notifyAll();
        System.out.println("Notifyall ok");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I don't understand why, after the first addToList(), the other threand won't wake up!

Comment: You are only conditionally unlocking it. Put the unlock into a `finally` block.

Comment: I can not use finally without a try, so what should I do?

Comment: Why does your code call `tryLock()`? If all you want is for the thread to wait until it can acquire the lock, then why don't you simply call `obj1.getLock().lock()`?